# How to validate SQL code / stored procedure correctness

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am an intern SQL developer and my boss asked me this question:

My client gave me a ***dataset*** of the year ***2019*** and the ***correct output***. We wrote a stored procedure taking in the dataset and returned the output similar to the client's output. So now our stored procedure is ***working correctly for the year 2019 dataset***.

Now how do I validate that the stored procedure ***works correctly for dataset of other years***?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So long as you haven't hard coded any dates in, it should be fine shouldn't it? But to be safe you probably want to carry out the same approach on another year i.e. validate that its returning the correct results. You can create SQL unit tests, but ultimately you need to create such tests, so you need sample data and expected results - which is how you validate any SQL query.

Comment: @DaleK I told my boss that I would parameterize all changing fields, and remove all hard-coded values, leaving just the pure algorithm in these sp. But it's not what he is looking for.

As for your answer, the only way to know it's working correctly is to have an expected result to compared to right? That is impossible for my case, because after knowing the sp works for 2019, the client will send real data and expect it to work correctly for any data. So there is no more expected output to compared to.

The question is how to make sure it works for all the years

Comment: I agree with @DaleK. The only thing I can think to add is that you can ask whether there are any nuances that apply to other years that might not show in the 2019 dataset -- getting additional special information for a product line that was only added in 2020, for example.

Comment: The only way to be sure it works is to test it against data. I would parameterise it as you say, ensure it runs against 2019, then ensure it runs against 2018. If you can write a generic query, i.e. with nothing hardcoded, that works correctly for 2 years, then its a pretty sure thing it will work for all years, because what else could go wrong?

Comment: It sounds to me that you're thinking in terms of transforming the data set, A, to the output data, B, and guessing at what the transformation from A -> B needs to be. But if you can pin down what the stored proc actually is supposed to do, i.e. "group by product line and calculate sales vs. cost of goods sold vs. year-over-year profit" it gets a lot easier to verify that it's doing it!

Comment: One approach to testing that's useful, by the way, is to think of edge cases, and see how your procedure handles them and whether the example output you have suggests that way is also what the client wants. For example, if there were sales for 10 different products in 2019, but only 8 of those products had sales in 2020, do they still want to see the extra 2 products listed with sales of 0 for the year, or have them not appear?

Comment: You can (and should) fabricate data for a number of different periods knowing exactly what that information should produce as an output of your procedure's logic. A simple way of doing this is to copy rows from your 2019 data while changing the "dates" to some other years (while tracking which ones you add so you can manually determine what the correct output should be).

Comment: And one more thing - you don't really know that your logic works correctly for 2019 since there is your database contains no data (presumably) for any other years. You can't know that until your test data spans multiple years. And note that 1 year and a month does not constitute "multiple years". Don't try to take the cheap, easy route to testing.

Comment: thank you so much @DaleK, Ann L and SMor. I think unit testing is the solution. Mocking up my own data with edge case with expected output is the way to validate the sp is working correctly, aside from the expected 2019 dataset. The only problem is that this dataset has A LOT of fields to mock up manually...

Answer (score 0):

To validate the procs and make sure they are correct, import the whole db to the database solution in Visual Studio and run a build to validate all objects.

Comment: Do you mean syntactically correct and compile successfully? This is not what I am looking for. I am looking for if it produces correct result on whatever dataset fed in. Thank you for your help